# Formatting emails from crontab with ssmtp

Tags: cron, printf, ssmtp

I've seen a number of examples on how to setup ssmtp but can't seem to find clear answers how to configure crontab to send data to an email.
What I want to accomplish is a crontab config that will send emails with system stats

- every 12 hours
- at each boot. (@reboot)

I've installed and configured ssmtp correctly since I can send emails by doing for example
`printf "Subject:Test\n\rthis is a test\n\r" |ssmtp mail@domain.com"`
and it works exactly as intended. However doing the exact same thing from cron results in command being treated as a string to mail. All backquotes are ignored.

Here I set it to every minute:

```
MAILTO="mail_user@domain.com"
* * * * * bash -c 'printf "Subject:Test\n\rthis is (`date`) a test\n\r" | ssmtp mail_user@domain.com'
```

And Receive:

```
SUBJECT:
Cron <user@host> printf "Subject:Test\n\rthis is (`date`) a test\n\r" |/usr/bin/ssmtp mail_user@domain.com` 
CONTENT:
bash: ssmtp: command not found
```

where **user@host** is my local user and pc host and **mail_user@domain.com** is the actual email that should be used to send data.
I tried providing full path /user/bin/ssmtp instead of just ssmtp to no avail

Disclaimer:
This is a reduced example, there's more data that I want to mail to my monitoring email (A gmail account)

**UPDATE**

I had to change form `/usr/bin/ssmtp` to `/usr/sbin/sftmp` which shows my problem is somewhat different than I initially thought. The emails are sent correctly, but at the same time crontab is sending the old "email" with command as string in subject. I removed all `MAILTO=` sections from my crontab, but while I can still send my correct emails, I still have CRON commands (not sure how to better phrase it) written out into my e-mail.

So to sum up - I'm getting **two** emails per crontab task, one being an actual email, and the other being delivery failure with atempt to mail username@hostname from email_user@gmail.com